# Search a selectbox for element containing specific string with javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, search, select

I have a selectbox containing some city names, and a search field.

When I search for a cityname in my searchbox, I would like it to search through the options in #selectzone_select and return the first element having html that matches the search, so I can redirect to the link in the value of that element.

**Selectbox**

```
<select id="selectzone_select">
  <option class="c1" value="/category/testcity1/">testcity1</option>
  <option class="c2" value="/category/testcity2/">testcity2</option>
</select>
```

**Searchfield**

```
    <form onsubmit="return searchZone(this)">
      <span id="zonesearchwrap">
        <input class="zonesearch" value="Search" name="searchtext">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
      </span>
    </form>
```

**searchZone()**

```
function searchZone(obj){
  var value = obj['searchtext'].value;
  // Find "#selectzone_select option" having value in text
  // If anything is found redirect to the option.value
}
```

Comment: This plugin does exactly what you want: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: check this another plugin http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/